# How to redirect a page from a splash screen (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a splash screen which should show an image as the background of the page and subsequently execute a rest call whose result is necessary to understand which other page to load (login or homepage), I cannot understand why the redirect is not working

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MainPage());
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Redirect managed from the server
// ---------------------------------------------------------
  Future<void> getRedirectPage(BuildContext context) async {
    await initializeSharedPrefs();
    ServerResponse serverResponse = await makeRequestToServer(Null);
    if (serverResponse.state.compareTo("") != 0) {
      if (serverResponse.state.compareTo("true") == 0) {
        if (serverResponse.redirect.compareTo("login") == 0) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_,__,___)=> LoginPage()));
        } else {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_,__,___)=> Homepage()));
        }
      } else {
        showAlertDialog(context, "Server error", "Something went wrong: " + serverResponse.msg);
      }
    } else {
      showAlertDialog(context, "Server error", "Something went wrong: " + serverResponse.msg);
    }
  }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialization of UI
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getRedirectPage(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ID - IoT',
      home: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.jpeg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error showed from the logcat:

```
E/flutter (18073): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

E/flutter (18073): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator
```

Comment: I guess it's because Navigation should happen inside "MaterialApp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a context to a function that does not store the navigator (the navigator is inside the material app). you can use builder widget.

```dart
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          getRedirectPage(context);
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
```

or use navigation key, but its not safety at this situation

```dart
    final navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    navKey.currentState!.pop();
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navKey,
      home:  Container(),
    );
```